# OpenCSV: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.getAllFields

Tags: spring-boot, opencsv, read.csv

I am trying to read csv files using OpenCSV dependency in my spring boot project. Getting below error while uploading my test file via postman

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.getAllFields(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;
> at
> com.opencsv.bean.util.OpencsvUtils.determineMappingStrategy(OpencsvUtils.java:67)
> ~[opencsv-5.7.1.jar:na]   at
> com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder.build(CsvToBeanBuilder.java:234)
> ~[opencsv-5.7.1.jar:na]   at
> com.personal.sahil.demo.processor.impl.CsvFileProcessor.readFile(CsvFileProcessor.java:32)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.personal.sahil.demo.service.impl.FileServiceImpl.uploadFile(FileServiceImpl.java:44)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.personal.sahil.demo.controller.FileController.pojoUpload(FileController.java:43)
> ~[classes/:na]

**Reference** : https://medium.com/@jha.minakshi892/parse-csv-file-to-java-model-c8d2c6727d09

**Details**

pom file

```html
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
   <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
   <version>5.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Code base

```java
public <T> List<T> readFile(Class<T> clazz, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    List<T> records = null;
    try (
            InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
            ) {

        CsvToBean<?> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withType(clazz)
                .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                .withIgnoreEmptyLine(true)
                .build();
        records = (List<T>) csvToBean.parse();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("error parsing csv file {} ", ex);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex.getCause().getMessage());
    }

    return records;
}
```

**Adding more info**
Getting below warning also. So, tried using   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") above method name. But no resolution.
Unchecked call to 'withType(Class<? extends T>)' as a member of raw type 'com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder'

**Solution which is working fine for me is below
**
pom file

```html
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
   <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

code

```java
try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader)) {
    String[] nextRecord;
    while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Name : " + nextRecord[0]);
        System.out.println("Email : " + nextRecord[1]);
        System.out.println("Phone : " + nextRecord[2]);
        System.out.println("==========================");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution and issue

I was using org.apache.commons, commons-lang3 dependency explicitly version 3.0

On checking code where it was breaking, i realised version issue
https://github.com/cygri/opencsv/blob/master/src/main/java/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java#L322

Updated my pom with version 3.12.0 and now its working fine